# how to display Iframe loading message during webview in phonegap build?

Tags: jquery, ajax, phonegap-build

I tried to make simple android app by using phonegap-build. I used just HTML5, CSS3 and Jquery to develop it. I want to implement Iframe webview in my app with a progress bar while the iframe loads .

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried this http://jsfiddle.net/CPadm/